# vba if cell contains any format of string

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching for the past hour as I cannot seem to find an example that goes over my use-case (although super simple in my mind). I have a for loop that searches through all the cells in a column and if a cell contains the string **Open**, then it adds data to a different cell. Issue I am having is sometimes the cell contains **open** or **Open 12/12/12** etc. Currently my code I have is below. I cannot figure out how to ignore case sensitivity and if cell contains this value, to change it to "Still open or closed".

```
If Cells(X, C) = UCase("Closed") Then
  Cells(X, Q).Value = "Closed"
ElseIf Cells(X, C) = UCase("Open") Then
  Cells(X, Q).Value = "Still open"
End If
```

This works if the cell only contains "Closed" or "Open". any different spelling or additional text in the boxes causes this to fail. Is there a simple way to search if the cell contains any format of the "StRiNG" I am searching for?

Comment: `If UCase(Cells(X, C).Value) like "*CLOSED*" Then`

Comment: Are `Q` and `C` column letters or number variables? because my guess is they are columns so change to `If Cells(X, "C")...`

Comment: @TimWilliams when to use which, `instr`/`like`?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any real difference: I was offering `Like` in addition to your `Instr`, not as the "right" way...

Comment: Oh. I was just curious. Figured a codewarrior like you had reasoning to choose one over another =P Edit: `instr` is more powerful given it gives you position which is unnecessary here.

Comment: @ScottCraner Q and C are number variables that get set based on earlier statements where I search for specific row/columns.

Comment: @findwindow I have been playing with the instr syntax for awhile and I gave up figuring I cannot use it in my `if` statement already as instr sets an exit code (or I thought it did)

Comment: @TimWilliams, That looks like exactly what I have been looking for. Super simple. You can post that as an answer if you would like to so I can accept it.

Comment: Go with Tim. `like` is sufficient here.

Answer (score 4):

To acccomplish **pattern matching**, a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) may be more appropriate.

```
Select Case True
    Case LCase(Cells(x, c).Value2) Like "*closed*"
        Cells(x, q) = "Closed"
    Case LCase(Cells(x, c).Value2) Like "*open*"
        Cells(x, q) = "Still Open"
    Case Else
        'something else
End Select
```

This will remove case sensitivity as well as searching for *closed* as a substring of the entire cell's contents.

Comment: I will go ahead and accept this answer tomorrow morning if Tim Williams does not post his (using his version), as yours is definitely a viable option. Thank you.